# Copying a large folder. Ubuntu stops responding!

Tags: 13.10, files

I needed to backup my files on an external hdd (my firend's hdd). I tried to copy a 400GB folder.

I failed for about 5 times. Ubuntu just becomes still. only the mouse moves.

Is this some ubuntu bug or is it my pc's bad specs?

my PC is a core2duo with integrated graphics, 2GB of ram and 2GB of swap. it has 300MB free space on the file-system partition.

edit: twice of those times (where ubuntu stops responding) were because I tried to open google chrome while it still was in progress. (that's when I learnt not to touch the pc till it finishes)

edit:
Tried to copy a 130GB folder to the hdd. I input the command `free -h` several times and here's the output

[image: outputs]

...then I went to create a new question on askubuntu for about 10 minutes. I finished and went back to the scene you have in the picture... input `free -h` in terminal ... terminal didn't post any output; just froze, then the whole computer froze (I know it from the launcher; I put the mouse on it, it expands and doesn't recoil) so I restarted the computer. Just as before

Comment: Try copying them in small pieces like 700MB at one time. Or there may be a problem within you friend's HDD. You can try copying same files in some other place like USB.

Comment: Can you check if memory is getting short on free space? Run `free -h` when copying to see how much free memory and swap you still have. I don't think that's the problem, though. Maybe if you try rsync?

Comment: @rainlover I have already finished the copying process the way you said (breaking the folder down). I just need to know what's wrong

Comment: @GabrielF okay.

Comment: It's just normal. A large file (kind of 5 or 6GB) you copy anywhere of course will make things slower as it is heavy too.

Comment: @GabrielF edited the question

Comment: Try to run nautilus with lower priority to see if the system still hungs. From a terminal run `nice -n 19 nautilus` (-20 is highest priority, 19 is the lowest priority. Default is 0), then copy the files using this instance of nautilus.

Comment: @GabrielF Tried your suggestion and it worked. I just left it overnight and found it complete the next day. would you post an answer? :)

Comment: -I'm sorry I haven't replied since a long time, my friend took his hdd back. there's kinda long story-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following GabrielF's replies in the comments, here's what might fix the problem

GabrielF suggested opening a nautilus window (files window) with a different priority.

command is `nice -n 19 nautilus` It will open a nautilus window. Do the copy operation from there. It should not fix the problem. I hope so